# Access elements in bootstrap modal with jquery

Tags: jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using [this](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal) angular-bootstrap modal.

Its content:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
    <div class="modal-body">
          <button id="my_button">Alert</button>
    </div>
</script>
```

I have tried these two options:

```
$("#my_button").click(function(){
    alert("ALERT");
})

$("#my_button").on("click", function(){
    alert("ALERT");
})
```

How to get access to that button?

Comment: You should be using `ng-click` with angular stuff!

Answer (score 1):

Wiht Angular JS you should be using ng-click to link event handlers to your buttons.

Like:

```
<a ng-click="iWillClick()">Click me</a>
```

Will execute the iWillClick function of your scope (in your relevant controller). Check [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick) out to understand how ng-click works.

So in your case, if your footer is:

```
<div class="modal-footer ng-scope">
   <button ng-click="ok()" class="btn btn-primary">OK</button>
   <button ng-click="cancel()" class="btn btn-warning">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

will execute the **ok()** function on OK and the **cancel()** function on cancel. Both of those should be on your controller.

If for any reason you would like to use normal jQuery for your event handlers you should do

```
$(".modal-footer .btn-primary").on("click", function(){
    alert("OK");
});

$(".modal-footer .btn-warning").on("click", function(){
    alert("CANCEL");
});
```

Comment: OK great) thanx! One more question: I have an images inside the modal, How do I show a loading gif until it loads?

Comment: How do you load? is it an Ajax call? If so then how do you invoke the ajax call? You can have an image <img src="loading.gif" ng-show="iAmLoading"> and set iAmLoading to true or false in your controller

Comment: I just have <img src={{ url }}>, url comes from controller

Comment: Could you post your controller and code here? If you prefer post a new question and let me know.